# How do I edit text on UI and update the change in localStorage with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to edit a task on a ToDo app and update the change in localstorage object. I have tried contenteditable to edit the text on UI. However, I can't update the change to the localstorage array. Here is the code I am working with. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

```
// Edit task
const eidtTask = (e) => {
   // Array of objects of tasks
   const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
   if(e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
        // When I click edit button I want to edit the task and update the value on localstorage array as well
   }
   localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a data attribute in the HTML element and have an `oldValue` in the local storage data with that you can update the local storage

Once the user click submits or completed editing, change the HTML data attribute and the `oldValue` in local storage.

```js
// Edit task
const editTask = (e) => {
  // Array of objects of tasks
  const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  if (e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
    for (const task of tasks) {
      if (task.oldValue === e.target.getAttribute('data-foo')) {
        task.value = e.target.value;
      }
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
};
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works with some slight modification. Really appreciate your assistance!